# R caret package (rpart)

Tags: r, text-classification, rpart

I get the below error when using rpart library

```
dt <- rpart(formula, method="class", data=full.df.allAttr.train);

Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = full.df.allAttr.train,  : 
  object is not a matrix
```

When i convert full.df.allAttr.trainto matrix

```
dt <- rpart(formula, method="class", data= as.matrix( full.df.allAttr.train));

Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = as.matrix(full.df.allAttr.train),  : 
  'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array
```

When i check for the class type its a data frame

```
class(full.df.allAttr.train)

[1] "data.frame"
```

thank you for the inputs , the error went off when i created the formula with the proper column name which has the outcomes.

```
measurevar <- "SpeakerName"
formula_str <- paste(measurevar, paste(rowNames, collapse=" + "), sep=" ~ ")
formula <- as.formula(formula_str)
```

It give a different error since my data frame has row.names as text below is the snapshot

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, data = full.df.train,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'character(0)')
```

[image]

Sorry new to this i will add the full source code and data sets

```
library(tm)
library(rpart)
obamaCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = "D:/R/Chap 6/Speeches/obama" , encoding="UTF-8"))
romneyCorpus <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = "D:/R/Chap 6/Speeches/romney" , encoding="UTF-8"))
fullCorpus <- c(obamaCorpus,romneyCorpus)#1-22 (obama), 23-44(romney)
fullCorpus.cleansed <- tm_map(fullCorpus, removePunctuation)
fullCorpus.cleansed <- tm_map(fullCorpus.cleansed, stripWhitespace)
fullCorpus.cleansed <- tm_map(fullCorpus.cleansed, tolower)
fullCorpus.cleansed <- tm_map(fullCorpus.cleansed, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
fullCorpus.cleansed <- tm_map(fullCorpus.cleansed, PlainTextDocument)
#fullCorpus.cleansed <- tm_map(fullCorpus.cleansed, stemDocument)

full.dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(fullCorpus.cleansed)
full.dtm.spars <- removeSparseTerms(full.dtm , 0.6)

full.matix <- data.matrix(full.dtm.spars)
full.df <- as.data.frame(full.matix)

full.df[,"SpeakerName"] <- "obama"
full.df$SpeakerName[21:44] <- "romney"

train.idx <- sample(nrow(full.df) , ceiling(nrow(full.df)* 0.6))
test.idx <- (1:nrow(full.df))[-train.idx]
rowNames <- colnames(full.df)

measurevar <- "SpeakerName"
formula_str <- paste(measurevar, paste(rowNames, collapse=" + "), sep=" ~ ")
formula <- as.formula(formula_str)
dt <- rpart(formula, method="class", data=full.df.train);
```

Fails at the last step

Data Sets are here
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1SogodTE-kJSHF6aFRmQURsV0U&usp=sharing

Comment: I imagine that is frustrating. you can you create a reproducible example

Comment: check the result of as.matrix( full.df.allAttr.train )

Comment: thank you for the inputs , the error went off when i created the formula right.                                                                                             { measurevar <- "SpeakerName"
formula_str <- paste(measurevar, paste(rowNames, collapse=" + "), sep=" ~ ")
formula <- as.formula(formula_str) }

Comment: @user2478236  You really need to edit your question and add the `dput` of your data.frame. How are we supposed to use an image? You should add the data.frame or part of the data.frame that creates the error you see. That's how we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include `full.df.train` and your formula is not fine.

This will work:

```
full.df.train <- full.df[train.idx, ]
dt <- rpart(SpeakerName ~ ., method = "class", data = full.df.train)
```

The problem with your formula is that you include `SpeakerName` in both sides of `~`. If you want to use all variables, using the `.`expression is much easier and compact.

Comment: thank you for the inputs @Lluis , will try this out.